# FilterType Property not working for Analytical Table

Tags: filter, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have used an analytical table for my view, where I want to implement cell filter capability for my Date fileds.
The cell filter works fine for the string values but for date values I am facing some strange issue.

I have tried to use property FilterType to define that the values are of type date but when I click on the filter option it takes the dates as a full date and not as the format that I have defined.

I have tried to give a source and a pattern in the filterType.Tried to give only the pattren but that also doesnt formats the values properly.

Table code:

```
<Table:Column width="9rem" filterProperty="NextReviewDate" filterType="\{type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: \{pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy' , UTC: true\}, constraints: \{\} \}" sortProperty="NextReviewDate">
                        <m:Label text="Next Review Date"/>
                        <Table:template>
                            <DatePicker id="datePicker_04" change="handleDateChange"
                                value="{path:'NextReviewDate', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions: { pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy' , UTC: true }}"></DatePicker>
                        </Table:template>

Format of the date n my oData service:
<d:NextReviewDate>2018-12-26T00:00:00</d:NextReviewDate>
```

[Screen shot of how the date appears currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TfcD.png)

Comment: can you show the code where you bind the input field (Filter) inside the popover?

Comment: I do not have any popover. I am making use of analyticalCoulmn Properties to do a cell level filter

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Date format, if you don't care about the time.

example with     `type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date'`

```
<Table:Column width="9rem" filterProperty="NextReviewDate" filterType="\{type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date'\} \}" sortProperty="NextReviewDate">
                    <m:Label text="Next Review Date"/>
                    <Table:template>
                        <DatePicker id="datePicker_04" change="handleDateChange"
                            value="{path:'NextReviewDate', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy' , UTC: true }}"></DatePicker>
                    </Table:template>
```

regards

Comment: I tried giving only type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date' as well but that also behaves the same.

Comment: Do we have any event available over the click of the cell filter? or is there a way to call a function in the propery FilterType? The documentation of the analyticalColumn mentions that we can call a function to format the date values but not sure how that really works

Comment: Have you already tried with JavaScript date/time (milliseconds after 1970)?
Make filters work on the data before it is formatted for display.